# Billing and Shipping address in Broadleaf Commerce

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I'm experimenting with Collect on Delivery (COD) orders in Broadleaf commerce and the question that I have is: how do I find out the Billing and Shipping address that the customer has entered for that particular order?

I can see that entries for both addresses get created in `blc_address` table.

I guess the Shipping address can be checked via `blc_fulfillment_group` (`address_id` and `order_id` columns) but how about billing address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you get that those details from Order entity
Include the orderService like

```
@Resource(name = "blOrderService")
protected OrderService orderService;
```

then query the order like

```
Order order = orderService.findOrderByOrderNumber(orderNumber);
//below is delivery address
order.getFulfillmentGroups().get(0).getAddress();
//and this is billing address
order.getPayments().get(0).getBillingAddress();
```